# how to activated click event on autocomplete search bar vue with router link

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have an app that is a github clone. I want to make search bar work like github. But my search bar on navbar on option section does want to click. I have give the option a event but still does not work.
here my code

```js
data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      filteredrepo: [],
      owner: "dimaswntech",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toRoute() {
      console.log("klilk", this.search);
      this.$router.push({ path: "/detail/" + this.search });
    },
```

```html
<b-nav-form>
            <input
              class="form-control input-repo"
              type="text"
              v-model="search"
              @input="searchData"
              autocomplete="off"
              list="my-list-id"
              placeholder="Search repo"
            />
            <datalist id="my-list-id" v-if="filteredrepo" @change="toRoute">
              <option v-for="filterre in filteredrepo" :key="filterre.id">
                {{ filterre.name }}
              </option>
            </datalist>
            <!-- <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"
              >Search</b-button
            > -->
          </b-nav-form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is the two-way binding method of vue.
Its equal to `v-bind:value` combined with `@input`.
I would remove the `@input`

```html
<input
  :value="text"
  @input="event => text = event.target.value">
```

```html
<input v-model="text">
```

Then you search data should include the value of your searchbar and you have to fire the `toRoute` method afterwards.